# Adding column with minimum date oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, calculated-columns

I have this table:

[image]

As you can see in the image, there are multiple dates for each record. I want to create an extra column with the minimum date for each record. I know how to do it in python but not how to do it in sql. How can I do that?

Comment: [MIN Analytic Function](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/min-and-max-analytic-functions#min)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a window function:

```
select a.*,min(a.date1) Over(Partition by a.record1) as min_date
from table_name a
```

This will add a column with the mininum date at a record level. Hope this helps.